# logrotate not working properly

Tags: centos, logrotate

I'm trying to setup logrotate but for some reasons logrotate isn't rotating the files. It always complains that it cannot find previous log files.

Below the content of my logrotate file:

```
/home/cm/dummy.log{
    rotate 4
    size 5K
    copytruncate
    delaycompress
    compress
    missingok
}
```

Running following command

```
logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/dummy
```

returns the following output:

```
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /home/cm/dummy.log 5120 bytes (4 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 1000
considering log /home/cm/dummy.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /home/cm/dummy.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20200327'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /home/cm/dummy.log.1 does not exist
renaming /home/cm/dummy.log.4.gz to /home/cm/dummy.log.5.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 4),
old log /home/cm/dummy.log.4.gz does not exist
renaming /home/cm/dummy.log.3.gz to /home/cm/dummy.log.4.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 3),
old log /home/cm/dummy.log.3.gz does not exist
renaming /home/cm/dummy.log.2.gz to /home/cm/dummy.log.3.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 2),
old log /home/cm/dummy.log.2.gz does not exist
renaming /home/cm/dummy.log.1.gz to /home/cm/dummy.log.2.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 1),
old log /home/cm/dummy.log.1.gz does not exist
renaming /home/cm/dummy.log.0.gz to /home/cm/dummy.log.1.gz (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /home/cm/dummy.log.0.gz does not exist
log /home/cm/dummy.log.5.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
copying /home/cm/dummy.log to /home/cm/dummy.log.1
set default create context to system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
truncating /home/cm/dummy.log
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
set default create context
```

When I check the folder after running this command I have an file called: dummy.log.1 with the exact same content as before the rotation and an empty dummy.log file.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing ?

Comment: A problem?  To me it seems that logrotate did what was expected of it.  What did you expect?

Comment: Well it should split the file in smaller files. Since the size of my dummy file is to big.

So I have dummy.log which is too big and I was expecting to split in (up to 5) smaller files.

Comment: I've never known logrotate to do that, there's no option to do it either.  If logrotate is run regularly, the logfiles should be smaller, one of the options is "size", telling to rotate when that size is reached.

Comment: Mmmm I was thinking cause the rotate command tells logrotate how many times it should rotate files before mailing or deleting them it would create four small files. So dummy.log.1, ..., dummy.log.4. But why does it than copy everything in dummy.log.1 with size way bigger than the limit I was setting in size

Comment: Size parameter tells logrotate when to rotate.  This is not the split command.  Only the program writing to the log, can decide it needs to switch when a given size is reached.  This is what I prefer.